# python-social-auth on django/heroku/github: session state value missing

Tags: django, github, oauth, python-social-auth

This question is specific to the python-social-auth OAuth framework, integrated with a Django application. It concerns the callback portion of the interaction.

The problem: After authentication success with GitHub provider, the response to https:///complete/github/?code=583etc&redirect_state=8f5b9etc instructs a redirect to my SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL with "Session State Value Missing" error.

What I want is my authorized user to proceed to SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

Application is running at heroku on gunicorn/19.3.0 under https://

Same application is successful on WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.6 under http//: (Meaning that the same GitHub user can authenticate into the application in this environment.)

Stack trace, http trace, Django settings dump: [all here](http://dpaste.com/1CYH759).

Pipeline and backend integration is shown to be functional in different environments.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'social.backends.github.GithubOAuth2',
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'apps.accounts.pipeline.get_user_teams',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

Protocol is https://, and these potentially relevant settings are currently applied. I have tried several combinations of true/false with the first 4.

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = 'True'
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = 'True'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = 'True'
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = 'True'
SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = 'True'
```

The solution to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617308/session-value-missing-after-redirect-with-django-python-social-auth) does not solve.

Expert advice will be most welcome!

Thank much!

Comment: Just some random tips: Double check if your GitHub redirect_url is configured properly. Also, check the protocol: http/https should be the same.