# Session state missing in python social auth

Tags: python, django, session, cookies, python-social-auth

I followed this tutorial (https://artandlogic.com/2014/04/tutorial-adding-facebooktwittergoogle-authentication-to-a-django-application/) and I am getting following error. I have hosted my server on a EC2- instance and I have a domain http://(xyz).com. I also saw answer of this question ([Session value missing after redirect with django python-social-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617308/session-value-missing-after-redirect-with-django-python-social-auth)) but I am not getting any help.
[image]

Here is the stack trace in text

```
 AuthStateMissing at /api/user/complete/google-oauth2/
Session value state missing.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://interviewmiles.com:8000/api/user/complete/google-oauth2/?state=9Sa5JSkbcAbbGzBtqpx6jtbLCuJPe6kJ&code=4/c4VTig14u7THYLd1M4VoTRf1dnq58wp6S68EbkSwhZs&authuser=0&session_state=8aa4e419c219643dc264950a24151457677d99ae..b805&prompt=none
Django Version: 1.9.7
Exception Type: AuthStateMissing
Exception Value:    
Session value state missing.
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/oauth.py in validate_state, line 88
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.10
Python Path:    
['/home/ec2-user/interviewmiles/login',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cors_headers-1.1.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib64/python27.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...

▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py in _wrapped_view_func
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py in wrapped_view
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/utils.py in wrapper
            return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/views.py in complete
                       redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/actions.py in do_complete
        user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/base.py in complete
        return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/utils.py in wrapper
            return func(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/oauth.py in auth_complete
        state = self.validate_state() ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/oauth.py in validate_state
            raise AuthStateMissing(self, 'state')
```

Comment: Please include the error and traceback as text rather than a near-unreadable and unsearchable screenshot.

Comment: @pvg I have added the error in text form.

Comment: did you figured out what problem that was?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Session value missing after redirect with django python-social-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617308/session-value-missing-after-redirect-with-django-python-social-auth)

Answer (score 4):

I managed to FINALLY solve this problem by setting

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True
```

in my settings.py file.

My production server uses nginx to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, and this was the cause for the session state to go missing.  Good luck-- hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by setting

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION = ['state']
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
```

in settings.py

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem because I was setting the Django configuration below. Removing it solved this error and I could log in normally.

```py
# DO NOT set this, it's what caused the error
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None"
```

I'm on `Django==3.1.8`

Comment: 2023 and this problem persist